# Identifying the next item in current for of loop iteration Typescript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, typescript, iterator

In my TypeScript project, I want to compare the values in an Array with the next value. If I am doing this in JavaScript I would do something like this:

```
//JS
for (var i = 0; i < codeBlocks.length; i++) {
    var j = i + 1;
    if (codeBlocks[i] > codeBlocks[j]) {return true;}
    return false;
}
```

However, I really like the Typescript for of syntax as it is much more readable.

```
//TS
for (let codeBlock of codeBlocks) {
    //logic
}
```

Is there a way of describing the "next iteration" value in the typescript for...of loop?

Comment: why dont you try  if (codeBlocks[i] > codeBlocks[i+1]) at the place of  if (codeBlocks[i] > codeBlocks[j])

Comment: @BunkerBoy I am only trying to implement that in TypeScript, the example was just to help explain the question.

Answer (score 6):

You can use [**`entries()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries)

```
for (var [index, codeBlock] of codeBlocks.entries()) 
{ 
  // your code you can use index 
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/m6sstkqc/)

Example snippet:

```
var test = ['a','b','c']
for (var [index, cur] of test.entries()) 
{ 
  var j = index + 1;
  console.log("Current value: "+cur+"  Next value: "+test[j])
}
```

Comment: How can he get next value in body of cycle?

Comment: i see. Well, i think it's wierd a litle

Comment: Its syntax looks different and little complicated. you can use `foreach` instead of `for` to improve code readability.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the index of an element , use the *foreach* function:

```
codeBlocks.forEach((item, index) => {
    console.log(item); // item in the array
    console.log(index); // item index in the array
});
```

Comment: Yes but his question was this "
Is there a way of describing the "next iteration" value in the typescript for...of loop?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use same syntax `for (var i = 0; i < codeBlocks.length; i++)` in TypeScript. But your cycle will run only once.

Comment: What do you mean by "your cycle will run only once"?

Comment: @torazaburo within first run of cycle it always returns from function. It means it breaks cycle on first run

Answer (score 0):

No. That's not the purpose of **for .. of**. You can read more about it [on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of).

You must use the `for (var i = 0; i < codeBlocks.length; i++)` syntax for that.

Comment: This is [typescript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/iterators-and-generators.html) and that is what it's for.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards for..of is not a typescript specific syntax. It's part of the ES6 standard. It's not meant to give you indexed access to the array though. You have the regular for or forEach for that (as JBaby posted).

Comment: Yes, but I am targeting es5 and TypeScript compiles for...of to what you have posted, so saying "That's not the purpose" doesn't really make any sense

Answer (score 0):

first Your javascript code is wrong, the last element will compare with undefined

maybe you should give a look to reduce function https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: "Wrong" is relative. Often a comparison with `undefined` will do exactly what is desired.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generator which generates pairs of elements:

```js
function *pairs(array) {
  let prev = array.shift();

  for (v of array) {
    yield [prev, v];
    prev = v;
  }
}

for (let pair of pairs([1,2,3])) { console.log(pair); }
```

If you want to also generate a last pair with the last value and undefined, then just add a `yield [prev, undefined];` at the end of the function.